# conversion of string to integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to convert to convert `nsstring` to `integer` in objective-c
can anybody help me in solving out this problem.

Answer (score 7):

try this may work for you :

```
NSString *str = @"42";
int x = [str intValue];
```

Comment: **Special Considerations**
On Mac OS X v10.5 and later, use integerValue instead.

Answer (score 3):

[NSString integerValue/intvalue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/integerValue)
This is assuming that the value is an integer, if it's not you will have more work to do, but you don't make that clear in your question.